# Returning a struct containing array in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, undefined-behavior

Can I return a struct that contains an array from a function or is it undefined beahvior?

Does it matter what standard I use?

For example:

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct struct_t{
    char arr[100];
    int number;
} struct_t;

struct_t func(void)
{
    struct_t s1 = {.number = 0};
    memcpy(s1.arr, "Hello World", sizeof("Hello World"));
    return s1;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct_t s2 = func();

    return 0;
}
```

Will it deep copy s1.arr to s2.arr?

if not, Will s2.arr try to point to the same location as s2.arr?

Maybe it creates a new array and only copies s1.number to s2.number?

Or is it just UB?

Comment: It'll be semantically equal to a deep copy but may invoke copy elision. It is not UB to do, and a fairly common way to pass arrays between functions without it being elided to a pointer.

Comment: It would be better to malloc and then return a pointer to the structure instead of returning the entire structure on the stack.  Depending on how deeply you nest these, you may end up running out of stack.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.  One array cannot "point to" the same location as another.  The storage of each object of structure type comprises the storage of each of its members, including arrays.

Comment: You have to go back to K&R 1st Edition (1978) to find a version of C without support for structures as arguments to functions and return values from functions, and that book forecast (accurately) that it would soon be a feature of C.  By the time I started using C (1983), the compiler I used had such support.

Comment: Is that deep copy as optimized as memcpy? Or is it better to use memcpy instead of assignment if I care about performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I return a struct that contains an array from a function or is it
> undefined behaviour?

As `struct`s and `union`s are passed to and returned from the function by ***value***, it is a **defined behaviour**. An array is the same struct member as any other type.

Bear in mind that **the whole** structure or union will be returned and it can be a costly operation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the array gets copied just like any other struct member, as if it was `char arr0, arr1, ..., arr99;` in the struct.

This is true since C89 (ANSI C), the first C standard.

Comment: Thanks, but is it true for every C standard or was it added later?

Comment: @nirki: C 1990 allows declaring functions that return structures containing arrays, but why do you ask? Are you writing new code that needs to conform to the 1990 C standard? You should not be using the 1990 C standard in new code unless it is essential to retrofitting something into very old code. However, there is a problem with arrays in structures that was not fixed until 2018. 2018 added some text giving such structures temporary lifetime.